# ServerName for Get-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionPolicy and Set-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionPolicy with Azure Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance, powershell-az-module

I am trying to set LTR on databases in our Managed Instances via the above listed Az commandlets.  The problem I am having is determining what the ServerName parameter should be.  If I try to use the ManagedInstanceName or FullyQualifiedManagedInstanceName it gives me the following error:

"Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource '[instnaceName]/[databaseName]'"

What should I use for this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the wrong commandlet.  The correct commandlet for Managed Instances is Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseLongTermRetentionPolicy